# VbScript if..else not working

Tags: vbscript

Here I want to check if the string contains text within it, but it's not working:

```
WScript.Echo "Hello"
Set oShell = CreateObject ("Wscript.Shell")
Dim strAgrs,strAgrs1,value,a,variable2,variable3,txt
a= execStdOut("wmic process where (Name like '%java.exe%') get commandline")
Wscript.echo a
variable2="java -cp ATMRETINA.jar com.elitenet.np.Cam2TakingSnapsV21"
variable3="java -cp ATMRETINA.jar com.elitenet.np.Cam1TakingVideoV11"
Wscript.echo variable2
Wscript.echo variable3
Wscript.echo inStr(a,variable2)
Wscript.echo inStr(a,variable3)
txt="This is a beautiful day!"
Wscript.echo inStr(txt,"beautiful")
if (inStr(a, variable2)>0) then
WScript.Echo "Hello friend video"
else
WScript.Echo "Hello friend video not working"
strAgrs = "cmd /c run_snaps.bat"
oShell.Run strAgrs, 0, false
end if

if (inStr(a, variable3)>0) then
WScript.Echo "Hello friend video"
else
WScript.Echo "Hello friend video not working"
strAgrs1 = "cmd /c run_video.bat"
oShell.Run strAgrs1, 0, false
end if
Function execStdOut(cmd)
   Dim goWSH : Set goWSH = CreateObject( "WScript.Shell" ) 
   Dim aRet: Set aRet = goWSH.exec(cmd)
   execStdOut = aRet.StdOut.ReadAll()
End Function
```

Even though it contains variable 2 and variable 3 within it, it always returns 0; I dont understand what's wrong.

Comment: Wscript.echo a -- does this shows you anything?

Comment: Instr comparison is by default case sensitive, could that be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

The problem has nothing to do with If or InStr. See

1. [.Exec Std* capture problems A](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/scriptcenter/en-US/35e94b7e-0b84-4890-be7f-5d7a3bc6700e/script-hangs-when-reading-output-of-command-inside-vbscript?forum=ITCG)
2. [.Exec Std* capture problems B](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/microsoft.public.scripting.wsh/kIvQsqxSkSk)
3. [WMIC outputs UTF16](https://superuser.com/questions/812438/combine-batch-wmic-ansi-unicode-output-formatting)

to understand, why you should WMI (not WMIC) as in

```
Dim WMI, Services, Service
Set WMI = GetObject("winmgmts:root/CIMV2")
Set Services = WMI.ExecQuery("select commandline from Win32_Process where Name like '%java.exe%'")
For Each Service In Services
  WScript.Echo Service.commandline
  If Instr(1, Service.commandline, "JAR", vbTextCompare) Then
     WScript.Echo "found JAR!"
  End If
Next
```

(stolen from Bill Stewart (1))

output:

```
java -jar "C:\rhino1_7R5pre\js.jar"
found JAR!
```

Comment: I just solved the problem by changing the name of the variables i.e variable2=com.elitenet.np.Cam2TakingSnapsV21 and                                   variable3=com.elitenet.np.Cam1TakingVideoV11 the problems might be the spaces in between :D